# How to capture RIGHT_CLICK in FlashDevelop?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flashdevelop

I wish to add an event listener for the `MouseEvent.RIGHT_CLICK` event in FlashDevelop.

In Flash CS6's editor, I can simply do:

```
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.RIGHT_CLICK, onMouse);
```

But `MouseEvent.RIGHT_CLICK` does not seem to exist in FlashDevelop.
I tried 'disabling' the context menu:

```
stage.showDefaultContextMenu = false;
```

But still to no avail. How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your FlashDevelop project settings target a Flash Player version high enough to support the [`RIGHT_CLICK`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/MouseEvent.html#RIGHT_CLICK) event; that being at least Flash Player **11.2**.

[image]

Comment: That worked like a charm, thanks! (Will accept answer after the time limit expires).